# Convert multi header and json input curl command in to powershell

Tags: json, powershell, curl, powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0

I have the below curl command which i am trying to convert to powershell, but i am not sure on how to handle the multi header inputs and the JSON input

Any help is highly appreciated

```
         curl --location --request POST 'https://anypoint.studio.com/cloudhub/api/v2/applications' \
     --header 'X-ANYPNT-ENV-ID:  4a96abfd4f5237cf1b64' \
     --header 'X-ANYPNT-ORG-ID: bc0d-3b9fd79234ad' \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer 3esede-a44b-29ab8841b508' \
     --form 'file=@"/C:/Users/pgi/Downloads/eafdc-flow-proxy-v1.2.jar"' \
     --form 'appInfoJson="{
\"domain\": \"testproxy-test\",
\"Version\": {
    \"version\": \"4.4.0\"
},
      \"properties\": {
    \"platform.client_id\": \"8f95qw3sa4b679aaa699cf0f5c6b6\",
    \"secure.key\": \"sYf%NJ7F^y&3lNRH*D$@\",
    \"env\": \"dev\",
    \"platform.client_secret\": \"acF0JHFUEFH8829a481D9c37EF364be7a\"
},
      \"propertiesOptions\": {
    \"secure.key\": {
        \"secure\": true
    },
    \"anypoint.platform.client_secret\": {
        \"secure\": true
    }
},
\"region\": \"us-west-1\",
\"monitoringEnabled\": true,
\"monitoringAutoRestart\": true,
\"workers\": {
    \"amount\": 1,
    \"type\": {
        \"name\": \"Micro\",
        \"weight\": 0.1,
        \"cpu\": \"0.1 vCores\",
        \"memory\": \"500 MB memory\"
    }
},
\"loggingNgEnabled\": true,
\"persistentQueues\": true
  }"' \
 --form 'autoStart="true"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `curl` with `Invoke-WebRequest` and parse the JSON with `ConvertFrom-Json`.

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $body
$j = ConvertFrom-Json $r.Content
```

I've left out setting the value of `$uri` and `$body`. I hope this is enough for you to get started with.

**Update**

First response was written too quickly. You probably need to pass header and body.

Like curl, Invoke-Webrequest is powerful and complex. You can find online documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp

You'll need to use the Headers and Body Parameters:

> -Headers <System.Collections.IDictionary>
>
> Specifies the headers of the web request. Enter a hash table or dictionary.
>
> To set UserAgent headers, use the UserAgent parameter. You can't use this parameter to specify User-Agent or cookie headers.
>
> Content related headers, such as `Content-Type` is overridden when a MultipartFormDataContent object is supplied for Body .

> -Body <System.Object>
>
> Specifies the body of the request. The body is the content of the request that follows the headers. You can also pipe a body value to `Invoke-WebRequest`.
>
> The Body parameter can be used to specify a list of query parameters or specify the content of the response.
>
> When the input is a GET request and the body is an `IDictionary` (typically, a hash table), the body is added to the URI as query
> parameters. For other request types (such as
> POST), the body is set as the value of the request body in the standard `name=value` format.
>
> The Body parameter may also accept a `System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent` object. This facilitates `multipart/form-data` requests. When a MultipartFormDataContent object is supplied for Body , any Content related headers supplied to the ContentType , Headers , or WebSession parameters is overridden by the Content headers of the MultipartFormDataContent object. This feature was added in PowerShell 6.0.0.

Looks like you'll have to create a `MultipartFormDataContent` object. Note this was added in PowerShell Version 6, so you can't use the Windows built-in default version 5. If you haven't already, you'll probably need to install the latest version of Version 7. (I use version 7 and it's great.)

So for headers you'd create something like:

```
$headers = [ordered]@{
    'X-ANYPNT-ENV-ID' = '4a96abfd4f5237cf1b64'
    'X-ANYPNT-ORG-ID' = 'bc0d-3b9fd79234ad'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer 3esede-a44b-29ab8841b508'
}
```

Then make a call like:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Post `
    -Headers $headers -Body $myMultipartFormDataContent
```

I haven't used `MultipartFormDataContent` so I'll leave that up to you. I hope this provides you with a good starting point.

Comment: So , the multiple headers can be passed in the body as arguments? No need to add Headers flag to the Invoke-WebRequest ?

Comment: I've updated my response to more directly address your question. Sorry I can't provide more help with MultipartFormDataContent.